# Dropdowns hide-then-slide again when clicking on item

Tags: jquery

I just need a small push with this one, I'm almost there.

There's a nav bar, its items display dropdowns when clicked on them, as you click from item to item the dropdowns collapse properly, but when you click on the same item to collapse its dropdown, the dropdown slides back up and then down again.

I created this **[demo in CodePen](http://codepen.io/rzea/pen/thIun)** - *(This demo is now working since I updated it with a working script. See my answer below)*.

This is the basic HTML structure I'm using:

```
<ul class="dd-container fll">
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <ul class="dropdown second-level-nav">
      <li><a href="#">SubLink 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SubLink 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SubLink 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <ul class="dropdown second-level-nav">
      <li><a href="#">SubLink 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SubLink 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SubLink 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <ul class="dropdown second-level-nav">
      <li><a href="#">SubLink 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SubLink 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SubLink 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="dd-container flr">
  <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cart</a>
    <ul class="dropdown second-level-nav">
      <li><a href="#">SubLink 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SubLink 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SubLink 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And this is the script I'm using:

```
//Nav bar dropdowns
$('.dd-container li').click(function(){     
    //Remove class .active from any other <li> and hide any other dropdown that's visible
    $(this).parents().find('.active').removeClass('active').find('.dropdown').slideUp();
    //Toggle class .active
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    //Slide up/down the actual dropdown     
    $(this).find('.dropdown').stop(true, true).slideToggle();
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: If I just remove this line  `$(this).removeClass('active');` it fixes the original problem, but the other menus wont slide up. Does this give a hint in the right way ?

Comment: @happybuddha I can't remove that line for usability reasons, the user should have a visual cue which element is active/selected. Thanks for the info though. Also, I think you meant `$(this).toggleClass('active');`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was a bit more work than I expected but I finally solved it.

happybuddha's and Jeevan's suggestions below were not an option because I needed to be able to toggle the item's class so the user can have a clear visual cue that an item is active/selected. Basically for usability reasons.

The **[CodePen Demo is working](http://codepen.io/rzea/pen/thIun)** now.

The working script is this one (not sure if this is the most optimal way of writing this script, but it works great):

```
//Nav bar dropdowns
var dropdown = '.dropdown';
$('.dd-container > li').click(function(){
  //Hide any other dropdown that's visible
  $(this).siblings().find(dropdown).slideUp();
  //Hide Cart dropdown
  $(this).parents('.dd-container').siblings().find(dropdown).slideUp();     
  //Toggle class .active
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  //Remove class .active from any other <li>
  $(this).parents().find('.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
  //Slide up/down the actual dropdown       
  $(this).find(dropdown).stop(true, true).slideToggle();        
});
```

For visual comparisons, here's the old script that wasn't working:

```
//Nav bar dropdowns
$('.dd-container li').click(function(){     
    //Remove class .active from any other <li> and hide any other dropdown that's visible
    $(this).parents().find('.active').removeClass('active').find('.dropdown').slideUp();
    //Toggle class .active
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    //Slide up/down the actual dropdown     
    $(this).find('.dropdown').stop(true, true).slideToggle();
});
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this: $(this).toggleClass('active');

> Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/full/BKhnD

Comment: I can't remove that line for usability reasons, the user should have a visual cue which element is active/selected. Thanks for the info though.